# Array.pop() não está funcionando

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um exercicio de programação, meu objetivo é criar um sistema de cadastro de convidados baseado em arrays. Nesse momento estou tentando implementar um sistema de filtro para barrar o cadastro de acordo com uma idade mínima, tentei fazer com o `Array.filter` mas não consegui, pois quero que apareça uma mensagem de alerta e não consegui implementar isso no filter.
Resolvi tentar fazer com o `pop()` e `if()`, em partes deu certo, o alerta aparece corretamente, porém o `pop()` não apaga o cadastro feito.
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa fazer?
Deixarei o código abaixo.

```
var convidados = [] 
        var idadeMinima = 18
        var barrados = []

       function cadastrar() {      
            var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value

            convidados[nome] = {nome:document.getElementById('nome').value , idade:Number(document.getElementById('idade').value) , genero:document.getElementById('genero').value , rg:document.getElementById('rg').value , cpf:document.getElementById('cpf').value}  

            filtrarIdade()
        }

        function filtrarIdade(){
            var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value

            if(convidados[nome].idade>idadeMinima){
                document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = 'O convidado foi cadastrado com sucesso!'
            } else{
                var barrados = convidados.pop()
                document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = `A idade mínima do evento é ${idadeMinima}!`
            }
        }
```

Comment: Não seria mais fácil validar antes de inserir o registro?

Comment: Seria, mas eu n tinha pensado nisso, quando fiz resolveu.

Comment: Se o seu problema está resolvido coloque como resposta o que você fez para resolver e escolha como resposta certa para fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Farei isso, obrigado, sou novo no stackoverflow, estou aprendendo sobre as praticas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em Javascript, não trabalhamos com arrays utilizando chaves nomeadas, quando tentamos fazer, nosso array será tratado como um Objeto.

Portanto, quando você executa:

```
convidados[nome] = { ... }
```

Você não está adicionando nenhum item ao seu array, você pode conferir isso adicionando um console.log logo abaixo:

```
console.log(convidados)
```

Para que sua implementação funcione corretamente, experimente alterar seu código para o seguinte:

```
var convidados = [] 
var idadeMinima = 18
var barrados = []

function cadastrar() {
    const convidado = {nome:document.getElementById('nome').value , idade:Number(document.getElementById('idade').value) , genero:document.getElementById('genero').value , rg:document.getElementById('rg').value , cpf:document.getElementById('cpf').value}

    convidados.push(convidado) 

    filtrarIdade()
}

function filtrarIdade(){
    var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value

    const convidadoSelecionado = convidados.find(convidado => convidado.nome == nome)

    if(convidadoSelecionado.idade>idadeMinima){
        document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = 'O convidado foi cadastrado com sucesso!'
    } else{
        barrados.push(convidados.pop())
        document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = `A idade mínima do evento é ${idadeMinima}!`
    }
}
```

**Observação**

É uma boa prática filtrar o convidado antes de adicionar ele ao Array de convidados

Comment: Segui sua observação e coloquei o filtrar antes do cadastrar, ficou mais mais fácil e limpo o código, agora tudo funciona corretamente. Sou iniciante na programação, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando o `array.push()` no lugar do `array[nome] = {...}`. Para colocar o filtro eu mudei a ordem dos comando, então assim que a function de cadastro é ativada o filtro de idade entra em cena antes do próprio cadastro e serve como um redirecionador, aqueles que são barrados entram em um array exclusivo assim como os convidados entram no array convidados.
Muito obrigado a todos pela ajuda, deixarei abaixo o codigo novo.

```
function cadastrar() {      
            var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value

            const convidado = {nome:nome , idade:Number(document.getElementById('idade').value) , genero:document.getElementById('genero').value , rg:document.getElementById('rg').value , cpf:document.getElementById('cpf').value}  

            filtrarIdade(convidado)                  
        }

        function filtrarIdade(convidado){
            var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value

            if(convidado.idade>= idadeMinima){
                convidados.push(convidado)
                document.getElementById('alerta').classList.remove('alerta')
                document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = 'O convidado foi cadastrado com sucesso!'
                listarCadastros()
            } else{
                barrados.push(convidado)
                document.getElementById('alerta').classList.add('alerta')
                document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = `A idade mínima do evento é ${idadeMinima}!`
                listarBarrados() 
            }
        }
```

**Observação**

 Adicionei o  `classList.add()` para mudar a cor do alerta quando o mesmo for negativo.